# Tikz - Custom Path Style with a Node to Label the Path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I would like to define a custom path style (egs. `skip loop` from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/diagram-chains/) and still be able to position a node at any position on the path (`midway`, `near end`, `at start`, `pos=0.3`, ect.). As soon as I use a customly defined style for the path, the node disappears. Please see the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    ,>=latex%
    ,skip loop/.style={to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}}%
    ]

    % bended path: node is visible
    \draw [<->] (0,0) to [bend left] node [near start,above] {x} (4,0);

    % custom path: node is invisible
    \draw [<->] (0,-1.5) to [skip loop=1] node [near start,above] {y} (4,-1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe_output]

I would like to use the `\draw` command and avoid the `\path` command. Is there a possibility?

Comment: You are missing `\tikztonodes` in your custom `to path` as the last item

Comment: simple as that. thank you. if you type an answer I will marked it as the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom `to path`s require the `\tikztonodes` macro to place the collected nodes on the path. So it should read

```
skip loop/.style={to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}}
```

to process the nodes.